# How can i convert HEX to ASCII and only get the number from it?

Tags: c#, hex, ascii, scale

I am receiving data from weighing scale(serial port) as HEX. I want to convert it to ASCII and only need the weight from it.
Code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (_serialPort != null && _serialPort.IsOpen)
            _serialPort.Close();
        if (_serialPort != null)
            _serialPort.Dispose();

        _serialPort.BaudRate = Convert.ToInt16(cbBaud.Text);
        _serialPort = new SerialPort(comboBox1.Text, BaudRate, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One); 

        _serialPort.DataReceived += SerialPortOnDataReceived; 
        _serialPort.Open(); 
        textBox1.Text = string.Format("Listening on {0}...", comboBox1.Text);

    }
    private delegate void Closure();
    private void SerialPortOnDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs serialDataReceivedEventArgs)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)     
            BeginInvoke(new Closure(() => { SerialPortOnDataReceived(sender, serialDataReceivedEventArgs); }));    
        else
        {
            while (_serialPort.BytesToRead > 0) 
            {
                textBox1.Text += string.Format("{0:X2} ", _serialPort.ReadByte()); 
            }
        }
```

This is my output:
Listening on COM1...20 20 20 30 0D 28 02 71 70 30 20 20 20 20 38 30 20 20 20 20 20 30 0D 28 02 71 70 30 20 20 20 20 38 30 20 20 20 20 20 30 0D 28 02 71 70 30 20 20 20 20 38 30 20 20 20 20 20 30 0D 28 02 71 70 30 20 20 20 20 38 30 20 20 20 20 20 30 0D 28 02 71 70 30 20 20 20 20 38 30 20 20 20 20 20 30 0D 28 02 71 70 30 20 20 20 20 38 30 20 20 20 20 20 30 0D 28 02 71 70 30 20 20 20 20 38 30 20 20 20 ....

[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6Oxd.jpg)

This is ASCII code that i converted manually from a website:

```
  0 
  (  q p 0         8 0           0 
  (  q p 0         8 0           0 
  (  q p 0         8 0           0 
  (  q p 0         8 0           0 
  (  q p 0         8 0           0 
  (  q p 0         8 0           0 
  (  q p 0         8 0
```

Comment: You have bytes array so you may use this: System.Text.Encoding.SomeEncoding.GetString(bytes)

Answer (score 1):

You have copied some expample but there are more suitable methods to read from serial port that would better suit your purpose.

First you need to determine the data format of the weighting indicator from the manual. Then you can use this (instead of the while loop):

```
string myData = _serialPort.ReadTo("\r");
```

where `"\r"` weight record delimiter (it could be also other strings like `<CR><LF>`, `<STX>` `<ETX>` etc.)

If you want to read all available input data from the serial port buffer, you can use

```
string myData = _serialPort.ReadExisting();
```

and split the string by specified char

```
string[] weightRecords = myData.Split('\r');
```

Then you parse the weight numeric values from the obtained strings. So you do not need to convert data from bytes, you can read it directly as a string. If you need more inspiration, check [this project](https://sourceforge.net/projects/netwico/).

---

If you want to try it, you can rewrite the body of your DataReceived handler like this:

```
    if (InvokeRequired)     
        BeginInvoke(new Closure(() => { SerialPortOnDataReceived(sender, serialDataReceivedEventArgs); }));    
    else
    {
         //There may be multiple records available in the Serial Port buffer
         string myData = _serialPort.ReadExisting();
         //Suppose that 0D character (equals to \r) marks the end of record, see manual of the indicator
         string[] weightRecords = myData.Split('\r');
         foreach (var s in weightRecords)
         {
              //9,5 = Position and length of the numeric weight value, for exact values see your weight indicator manual
              textBox1.Text += string.Format("{0} kg \n", s.Substring(9,5)); 
         }
    }
```

To split your string by delimiters consisting of multiple chars, you can use something like this:

```
string[] stringSeparators = new string[] {
  System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(new byte[] {0x0d, 0x28})
};
string[] weightRecords = myData.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. I am actually new on programming and just trying to find some codes and editing them. Should i remove only the while loop or should i remove whole if and else block?